# One command to restore local PostgreSQL dump into kubectl pod?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm just seeing if there is one command to restore a local backup to a pod running `postgres`. I've been unable to get it working with:

`kubectl exec -it <pod> -- <various commands>`

So I've just resorted to:

`kubectl cp <my-file> <my-pod>:<my-file>`

Then restoring it.

Thinking there is likely a better way, so thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `pg_restore` command directly in the pod specifying path to your local file as a dump source (connection options may vary depending on image you're using), e.g:

```
kubectl exec -i POD_NAME -- pg_restore -U USERNAME -C -d DATABASE < dump.sql
```

Comment: this is not helpful if the pod is in an isolated network and you want to get the backup file from your laptop into the pod.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was in s3 or another location available to the pod, you could always have a script inside the container that can download the file and perform the restore, in a single bash file.
That should allow you to perform the restore in a single command.

Answer (score -1):

cat mybackup.dmp | kubectl exec -i ... -- pgrestore ...

Or something like that.